# Find slash between 2 strings that are not inside an url string

Tags: javascript, regex

im looking for a method/regex to find the slash between 2 strings and add a &nbsp (space) to it.
I want to exclude html tags and urls from that.

I've tried `\/(?![^<>]*>)` to find/replace the slash, that excludes html tags too.

`string.replace(new RegExp('\/(?![^<>]*>)', 'gm'), '/&nbsp;');`

What can i do, to exclude urls aswell from that regex?

RegexTester: https://regex101.com/r/40DzZP/1

**Example:**

IN

```
1.) test1/test2
2.) <span>test1/test2</span>
3.) www.test1.com/test2
4.) www.test1.com/test2/test3
5.) <a>www.test1.com/test2</a>
6.) <a>www.test1.com/test2/test3</a>
7.) test1/test2 www.test1.com/test2 test3/test4
8.) <div>test1/test2 www.test1.com/test2 test3/test4</div>
```

OUT

```
1.) test1/&nbsp;test2
2.) <span>test1/&nbsp;test2</span>
3.) www.test1.com/test2
4.) www.test1.com/test2/test3
5.) <a>www.test1.com/test2</a>
6.) <a>www.test1.com/test2/test3</a>
7.) test1/&nbsp;test2 www.test1.com/test2 test3/&nbsp;test4
8.) <div>test1/&nbsp;test2 www.test1.com/test2 test3/&nbsp;test4</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check if The string is valid URL with  ```new URL(str)```

Comment: You can break the string into HTML tags, URLs and normal text and only process the text.

Comment: Reg Exp over HTML is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input string looks like HTML, you can parse it as HTML, go through all the nodes, split the nodes' text into different component and process all those components if they are not URLs, here is an example:

```js
const input = `test1/test2
<span>test1/test2</span>
www.test1.com/test2
www.test1.com/test2/test3
<a>www.test1.com/test2</a>
<a>www.test1.com/test2/test3</a>
test1/test2 www.test1.com/test2 test3/test4
<div>test1/test2 www.test1.com/test2 test3/test4</div>`;

const urlRegExp = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/i

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
[...doc.body.childNodes].forEach((c) => {
  const splitted = c.textContent.split(" ");
  const processed = splitted.map(part => {
    if (!urlRegExp.test(part.trim())) {
      return part.replace(/\//g, "xxxx")
    }
    return part;
  });
  c.textContent = processed.join(" ");
});

const output = doc.body.innerHTML.replace(/xxxx/g, "/&nbsp;");

console.log(output);
```

You may want to change the `urlRegExp` I'm not sure if it matches all valid URLs or if it has false positives.